# cron job to execute r script not working

Tags: r, cron

I am new to cron. I want to execute r script on regular basis using cron. I just added the job to crontab to check if it is working. But unfortunately, nothing is working. I wrote a test script and scheduled it for every 5 mins in cron job.

Here is test R script:

`print('HI')`

cronjob:
`5 * * * * sudo Rscript /path/to/script/test.R`

but when I execute it from terminal, it works fine.

terminal command:
`sudo Rscript /path/to/script/test.R`

Please tell me if I am missing something here. I was trying to make it run for every 5 minutes.

Comment: Is there any reason to run the script as superuser?

Comment: `sudo` almost certainly won’t work because it will require you to enter a password.

Answer (score 0):

Change the **permissions** of the file /path/to/script/test.R and make sure, it has execution permissions to the user you are trying to submit the cronjob.

`chmod 777 /path/to/script/test.R`

Alternately, you can also try below mentioned ways also

Create a shell file (i.e., sample.sh) and place the following code in it. Rscript /path/to/script/test.R , and schedule the cron job as mentioned below.

`5 * * * * /path/to/script/sample.sh`