# CRON not executing R script file

Tags: r, cron

I am trying to automate running of a script (test.R) in R stored on a desktop folder (cron_test). I am using CRON in my mac terminal. The example R script generates random numbers, plots them, and saves them to a PDF:

```
setwd("~/Desktop/cron_test")

pdf("example_plot.pdf", width = 8, height = 8)
plot(rnorm(100))
dev.off()
```

My CRON code attempts to call this every minute, but nothing appears in the folder:

```
* * * * * Rscript /Users/username/Desktop/cron_test/test.R
```

Nothing is being generated. I have tried the following:

- The file runs fine if I call it from the terminal, suggesting there is not an issue with the code:

  `Rscript /Users/username/Desktop/cron_test/test.R`
- I have also ensured (and double-checked) that the permissions iof the file has executable permission, as per [this proposed answer to a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098235/cron-job-to-execute-r-script-not-working):

  `chmod 777 /Users/username/Desktop/cron_test/test.R`
- I have also tried the other proposed solution from this answer, which is to create a shell file that calls the R script. This doesn't work, either.

I am receiving mail to state that the CRON task has run, but no output is appearing in my cron_test folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the mail say

```
/bin/sh: Rscript: command not found
```

?

If so, try using the full path to `Rscript`. You can find this from the terminal with

```
$ which Rscript
```

The reason for this is that the environment you get in a cron session is much smaller compared to that in an interactive terminal. You can examine this by comparing the outputs of

```
$ /usr/bin/env > env-interactive
```

and the cron job

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/env > env-cron
```

We can see these are quite different by counting the number of lines in each file.

```
$ wc -l env-{interactive,cron}
      20 env-interactive
       8 env-cron
```

In particular the shell executable search path (`$PATH`) in the cron job is much shorter

```
$ grep PATH env-{interactive,cron}
env-interactive:PATH=/Users/hpcchris/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/munki:/opt/X11/bin:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS:/Users/hpcchris/bin
env-cron:PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
```

(Using the full path `/usr/local/bin/Rscript` worked for me with R on my macos High Sierra laptop and produced the plot.)

Comment: Strangely enough, the email was producing no errors at all. Everything seemed to be running fine. However, if I add the full path to the utility Rscript (which I found via your recommended which Rscript) at the front of my cron call then it works fine! So, I have used:

    * * * * /anaconda3/bin/Rscript /Users/username/Desktop/cron_test/test.R

and it works just fine. (I am not sure why the utility Rscript was there, but that's a different thread...). Thanks for your help!