# Rscript in Crontab not running in Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: r, cron, ubuntu-18.04, ubuntu-server, rscript

The following is my very simple Rscript called `test.R` that I want to run every minute

`print("Hello, World!")`

and I would like to automate this script in the hopes that I can do the same for future scripts. I use the `crontab -e` call and add the following:

```
* * * * * Rscript home/<username>/test.R
```

which fails to produce any results.

Per the examples of [cron job to execute r script not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098235/cron-job-to-execute-r-script-not-working) and [Schedule a Rscript crontab everyminute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38778732/schedule-a-rscript-crontab-everyminute), I have made the following variations in the crontab code

```
* * * * * Rscript "home/<username>/test.R"
* * * * * usr/bin/Rscript home/<username>/test.R
* * * * * usr/bin/Rscript "home/<username>/test.R"
* * * * * cd home/<username>/ && Rscript test.R
* * * * * cd home/<username>/ && usr/bin/Rscript test.R
```

all of which do nothing. I have also created a script called `myScript.sh` which contains `Rscript /home/<username>/test.R`, and tried assigning the task `* * * * * home/<username>/myScript.sh` all to no avail.

I have made sure to run `chmod +x` to make my files executable beforehand, and simply typing `Rscript test.R` produces my desired results.

What else can I do to make this work? Is there some issue with me running Ubuntu Server 18.04 vs running the desktop version?

### Update

I have run all the above variations, with a `/` before `home` and `usr`. I have also switched to trying `~/test.R` but I still get no results.

Comment: Put a slash in front of `home`, ie make it `/home/<username>/test.R` or, equally, `~/test.R`.

Comment: I tried what you have suggested, and updated my question to reflect that. It still isn't working. Is there some sort of command that I have to run anytime I update a cron job?

Comment: This is elementary Unix, and there will be several hundred near-identical questions here, and the unix stackexchange site and the sysadmin stackexchange site.  Do `date > /tmp/filestamp.txt` and then you see when it ran.  Build up from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that it is running correctly and the results are not being captured?  Cron won't return results to active terminal.

The following worked for me on an Ubuntu Server 16.04

**First, confirmed that the test script return was expected when run from Rscript terminal:**

```
root@mytester:~/myrscripts# Rscript test.R
```

returns

```
  [1] "Hello, World!"
```

**Second, setup cron job via:**

```
crontab -e
```

entered this line

```
* * * * * Rscript ~/myrscripts/test.R >> ~/mycronlog.log
```

notice I am piping results to a log (appending)

**Third, checked log after a few minutes:**

```
root@mytester:~# cat mycronlog.log 
[1] "Hello, World!"
[1] "Hello, World!"
[1] "Hello, World!"
[1] "Hello, World!"
[1] "Hello, World!"
```

Comment: I completely spaced that I had to assign the output to a file. This also successfully works when needing to run my Rscript.